# How to integrate Spring Cloud with AWS Secrets Manager?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-cloud

I'm trying to integrate Spring Cloud application with the AWS Secrets Manager.

While doing, I'm having issue finding example code for Spring Cloud and the AWS Secrets manager integration. I have got the spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config in our pom, looking at the [official docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/2.1.x/multi/multi__cloud_environment.html#_integrating_your_spring_cloud_application_with_the_aws_secrets_manager).

As per this documentation, I need to just add property sources in a certain way, but I'm unsure how it can select the correct secrets?

If my application is called com.example.test does that mean my secret should be called secret.com.example.test and anything I add in there will automatically be available as a property source?

Do I even need to add any code for this to work? or Could you provide any other sources to complete this?

Answer (score 3):

This library is not super intuitive and took me a bit to figure out. Sounds like they [may be revamping](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/607) this a lot soon but as of spring-cloud-aws:2.2.3.RELEASE I got it working like this:

#### Authentication

Make sure you have your profile configuration in a <USER_HOME>/.aws/credentials file with a [default] profile

#### Region

In version 2.2.3 there is a [bug](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/639) that defaults the region to us-west-2 unless this is specified in your bootstrap.yml

```
aws:
  secretsmanager:
    region: <whatever region you'd like>
```

#### Secrets Manager

Make a secret named `/secret/application`. For now, add a key/value pair "password:secret"

#### Code

These key/value pairs will be directly mapped to properties, so you should now be able to just throw this in your Spring app. Your `password` variable will now have the value "secret"

```java
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Value("${password}")
    public String password;
}
```

That's the basics. If you [read the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/2.2.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#integrating-your-spring-cloud-application-with-the-aws-secrets-manager) they describe how to determine which secrets are checked on startup. In your example, by default it would also be checking `/secret/com.example.test` in addition to `/secret/application`